# FOSUserbundle security setting

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserbundle

my security setting is like this so,if you access under  /member
without login,you are transferred to Top page.

I want to add another behaivor.

If You access on toppage when you are logging in,you are transffered /member/profile

How can I make it?

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:


        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                provider: fos_userbundle
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }


        - { path: ^/member, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: do you want to redirect to `/member/profile` after login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many solutions to your problem :

In the `toppage` controller you can redirect the user if he is logged in.

Or

You can use an event listener on `kernel.request` which as the responsibility to set the response if the current route is `toppage` and the user is logged in.

edit:

To redirect in controller: `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('routename'))`

see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Comment: Can I redirect with in Controller ?? I want to call url '/member/profile' from the indexAction() of /Acme/TopBundle/Controller/DefaultController.

Comment: or Should I make redirect html page such as '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/"> ' ?? I just guess its not cool.